# What font is used in the 2014 Snowball Summit logo?

Tags: font-identification

Does anyone have any idea on what font this is?

[image: Snowball Summit 2014 logo]

Seen at http://snowballsummit.webflow.com

Comment: Hi! Welcome to GD. For [tag:font-identification] questions, we ask that you keep it to one font per question. It's also helpful to upload an image so that there is no ambiguity and so that other users aren't forced to click away from our site. I have edited your post to follow the correct format, please do the same in the future!

Comment: We also have a [wiki page](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) that lists some resources for identifying fonts. I recommend utilizing those services first; if it doesn't work out then come back and post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outage: http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=outage

Designed by Dave Whitley for Lost Type Coop.

Comment: The "W" had a little modification to correspond with the "B" effect.